# How to get browsing history report date-wise in Firefox?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, history, browsing, firefox-3.6

How to get browsing history report date-wise in Firefox?

by default it shows monthly, weekly and last day. I need to know for each day.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you go to History>Show All History (Or press Ctrl+Shift+H) you get a dialog with all your history in it.
Right click on the background of the column titles (ie "Name", "Tags", "Location", etc.) and make sure "Visit Date" is checked.  You now have a column that shows the date visited, and you can sort by date visited.

Comment: +1 OK. Thanks I got it. but is there i way gate date-wise folders. Actually I wanted like that.

Comment: That's what I figured you were looking for, but there's no way I know of to do that with default FF.  Those addons that mic84 listed look promising.

Answer (score 1):

These save history by date
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/682/
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/14642/
This  saves bookmarks by date only.
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/182864/

Comment: Thanks for this addons but I'm asking for history, not bookmarks

Comment: @ metal gear solid Sorry, I hope these are a bit closer

Answer (score 0):

**Better History NG** shows firefox browsing history grouped by day (in day, week, or month view).

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/better-history-ng/

*Example screenshot of history grouped by day, in month view:*
[image: Example screenshot of month view, history grouped by day, from Better History NG firefox addon]
*(more screenshots can be seen on add-on page)*